# Get Cell position in UITableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am trying to get position of cell in tableview. from this code i am getting cell position

```
int numberOfSections = [UITableView numberOfSections];
int numberOfRows = 0;
NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath = nil;
UITableViewCell *tempCell = nil;
for(int i=0;i<numberOfSections;i++)
{
     numberOfRows = [UITableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
     for(int j=0;j<numberOfRows;j++
     {
           tempIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i];
           tempCell = [UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:tempIndexPath];
           NSLog("Y postion for cell at (Row = %d,Section = %d) is :%f",tempCell.frame.origin.y);
     }  
}
```

it is calculating y axes of cell in tableview but my problem is i want to get the cell position in the visible area of tableview rect. ie if table view has size cgrectmake(0,0,200,500)
and cell height is 100 pixels. so tableview will show 5 rows. if i scroll down and select 7th row. i will get its y axes 700. but the cell will be within (0,0,200,500) frame.
How can I get cell location within this frame (0,0,200,500).

Comment: Your log is wrong **NSLog("Y postion for cell at (Row = %d,Section = %d) is :%f",tempCell.frame.origin.y);**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**NOTE**:I hope, question might have updated again, please use the other answers that may applicable to you.

You can use the `visibleCells` method which will return the currently visible cells in your tableview:

```
NSArray *visibleCellsList=[tableview visibleCells];

for (UITableViewCell* currentCell in visibleCellsList) {

    NSLog(@"cell : %@ \n\n",currentCell.textLabel.text);

}
```

Answer (score 228):

To get the position of a `UITableViewCell` relative to the view, in which the `tableView` is located (e.g. relative to your visible area):

*Swift 5 (and also Swift 4, Swift 3):*

```
let rectOfCellInTableView = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
let rectOfCellInSuperview = tableView.convert(rectOfCellInTableView, to: tableView.superview)
    
print("Y of Cell is: \(rectOfCellInSuperview.origin.y)")
```

*Objective-C:*

```
CGRect rectOfCellInTableView = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
CGRect rectOfCellInSuperview = [tableView convertRect: rectOfCellInTableView toView: tableView.superview];

NSLog(@"Y of Cell is: %f", rectOfCellInSuperview.origin.y);
```

*Swift 2 (really?):*

```
let rectOfCellInTableView = tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
let rectOfCellInSuperview = tableView.convertRect(rectOfCellInTableView, toView: tableView.superview)

print("Y of Cell is: \(rectOfCellInSuperview.origin.y)")
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to get it relative to the `contentView` of the table's scrollView? I.e. relative to the top of the scrollable content?

Comment: I am wowed. Thanks. Though I am late: if you could be so kind as to explain why your answer works, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Make it as Accepted Answer!

Answer (score -3):

I did it like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

That was all I had to do, than I could all `cell.frame`, `cell.bounds`, etc.