# Scrollable floating action button using swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

i am trying to achieve something close to the image below.[image]

and i have used the floating action button from this link [enter link description here](https://github.com/lourenco-marinho/ActionButton).

i am having trouble setting the auto layout constraints to look almost like in picture i have attached. The floating action button has to be placed between the table view head and tableview cell. but the constraints must be set with respect to the tableview cell.

ones the button reaches the top it should glide just below the navigation bar!!

any ideas guys?
Thank in advance.

Comment: May be you can try getting position of first table cell using [rectForRowAtIndexPath](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12498289/437146). Then dynamically set constraints for floating button

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. let me try that.