# Swift 3 - How to take a screenshot of specific UITableView row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to have a screenshot of a specific UITableView row and remove/add content to the cell before the screenshot.

For example: the cell contains only a text and a share button. On share button click, I want the app to generate an image with the **text** and my app **logo** on the top (**without** the **share** button).

What is the best approach to do this? and how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283807/how-to-take-screenshot-of-portion-of-uiview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283807/how-to-take-screenshot-of-portion-of-uiview)

Comment: @NiravHathi Thank you, but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: so you have image with your logo and you just have to add text on it?

Comment: @NiravHathi Yes

Comment: so look at this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906914/how-do-i-add-text-to-an-image-in-ios-swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906914/how-do-i-add-text-to-an-image-in-ios-swift)

Comment: @NiravHathi Thank you ver much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Nirav already gave you a hint in the comment section with this post: 

[How to take screenshot of portion of UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283807/how-to-take-scre%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Benshot-of-portion-of%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B-uiview)

So, you have now to get the Rect of the cell in the superview, so i made a sample action method:

```
@IBOutlet var snapImageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func snapshotrow(_ sender: Any) {
    //get the cell
    if let cell = myTable.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as? MyCustomCellClass {
        //hide button
        cell.shareButton.isHidden = true

        let rectOfCellInTableView = myTable.rectForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
        let rectOfCellInSuperview = myTable.convert(rectOfCellInTableView, to: myTable.superview)
        snapImageView.image = self.view.snapshot(of: rectOfCellInSuperview)

        let finalImage = saveImage(rowImage: snapImageView.image)
        //test final image
        snapViewImage.image = finalImage
    }
}

func saveImage(rowImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let bottomImage = rowImage
    let topImage = UIImage(named: "myLogo")!

    let newSize = CGSize.init(width: 41, height: 41) // set this to what you need
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)

    bottomImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
    topImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

and I was able to get the snapshot of the 0th cell of my table view and assigned it to the `snapImageView`.

Now the last step is to save the image to the camera roll, there are lots of related post out there in SO.

Source: [Get Cell position in UITableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623957/get-cell-position-in-uitableview)

Adding logo and hiding share button: [Saving an image on top of another image in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062225/saving-an-image-on-top-of-another-image-in-swift)

Comment: Thank you,  this solves the problem if the screenshot. But still I need to dd the app logo to it

Comment: answer updated with adding logo over image and share button hide

Comment: It's not taking the proper screenshots.