# How to remove blur view for particular cell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9, uiblureffect

I am using `UITabBarController` & `UITableView` My goal is to remove blur view for particular cell. Yes there is a way to add/remove `UIBlurEffect`to all the cell & bottom-Tabbbar But of-course don't want this at all .

For reference i am attaching screenshot

[image]

Comment: you can add blur view in cellforrow ta indexpath method and in that particular cell you not need blur you not add in that cell.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is to add Blur view to full screen except target cell. 
as tableivew resues cell so you have only option left is

You can take screenshot of particular cell

Here is code sample

[Swift 3 - How to take a screenshot of specific UITableView row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384573/swift-3-how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-specific-uitableview-row)

After that create Blur view for entire full tableview and add screenshot image to Y position of target cell

Comment: Yes, That might work. Can't we do something custom blur? where certain coordinates are escape from blur.

Comment: @Ramesh I don't think there is any workaround for this. or I might not aware if any.

Comment: Actually i also used `blurView.bringSubView(toFront: cell)` but that doesn't work :(*